# Generics + Interfaces in Java

Tags: java, generics

Consider this example:

```
class Parent<T> implements MyInterface<T> {...}
class Child1 extends Parent<ConcreteType1>{...}
class Child2 extends Parent<ConcreteType2>{...}
```

and then the following factory:

```
public class Factory<T> {
    public static <T> Parent<T> getChild(Type type) {
        switch (type) {
            case value1:
                return new Child1();
            case value2:
                return new Child2();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Type` parameter is just an `enum`.

Now,

- if I leave the things as above, I get the following error: cannot convert `Child1` to `Parent<T>`
- if I remove the generics, leaving just `Parent` and not `Parent<T>`, I get a warning

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What is `ConcreteType1`?

Comment: Do you have control over the `Type` enum?

Comment: Try <T extends Parent<?>> T getChild

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method does not really know the exact type of `T`, so you could just return a `Parent<?>`:

```java
public static Parent<?> getChild(Type type) {
    ...
}
```

Or, you could extend the `Type` class to actually construct the children, and with that you would have control over the exact output:

```java
public static <T> Parent<T> getChild(Type<T> type) {
    return type.createChild();
}
```

Comment: I do not see `getCertificationLabel(type)` so I can't say what the problem is. The second solution would unfortunately not work with enums, `Type` would have to be a normal class. Can you make them something other than enums?